# Extend datejs to parse string 25 Apr 2013 1200

Tags: javascript, datejs

How can I Extend [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) to parse "25 Apr 2013 1200" ?

Comment: Be aware that [Datejs is abandoned](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to use [`Date.parseExact`](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact):

> `Date.parseExact ( String dateString, String formatStringOrArray ) : Date`
>
> Converts the specified string value into its JavaScript Date
>   equivalent using the specified format (string) or formats (array). The
>   format of the string value must match one of the supplied formats
>   exactly.

**Example:**

```
Date.parseExact("25 Apr 2013 1200", "d MMM yyyy Hm");
```

**REF:** https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact